# Supercapacitor charge current

Tags: supercapacitor

i would like to buy a supercap for my project, something small likes 5F 10V .

I have read some datasheet about supercap, but i do not completely understand if i can charge a super cap with, for example, 1 o 2 Amps of current to charge it super fast. According to the ESR.

I will use a DC-DC converter with fixed Amperes and 9V with a zener diode.

For example, this datasheet (http://www.vishay.com/docs/28409/196hvc.pdf) give me a "RECOMMENDED charging current", but that(https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_S6017_FS.pdf) does not.

Comment: both your links point to the same datasheet

Answer (score 3):

That's two different revisions of the same data sheet.  The later one (July 2018) has recommended charge current.  You should assume the later one is the most up to date.

It offers both a recommended charge current and a max charge current (as well as discharge currents) in Table 3.  For the modest cap you want to use, the max is on the order of tens of mA.

EDIT:

In response to the corrected links, the second datasheet doesn't provide a charge current recommendation, but does recommend the resistor in the charge path, which amounts to the same thing.  I'm not willing to read the whole datasheet for you, but the 5F cap has a 100\$\Omega\$ charging resistor recommendation, which would correspond to 120mA for a 12V source

Comment: Sorry i edited the links correctly.
If i want to use that cap, i need to set a current limit at the "recommended charge current"?

Comment: @MarkCalaway I'll edit the answer to your edit.

Comment: I understand, probably I need to write at the manufacturer to know what happen if i force much current (charge/discharge) in to the cap. I see very often to charge with 1A or discharge with short circuit  some caps .

Comment: I suspect heat damage due to effective series resistance.  You likely wont get an answer unless you're talking about a very large purchase - in which case ypu should be talking to a large distributor.  Your needs are off by a factor of 10!  Find a new approach